# how to rearrange recursive JSON into tree structure with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I would like to transform the following JSON into another structure.

The source JSON:

- values = array with objects which needs to filtered by action === 'commented'
- comment = object with the comment, n Tasks and n Comments
- Comments can have endless more Comments and Tasks

---

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "action": "COMMENTED",
      "comment": {
        "text": "comment text",
        "comments": [
          {
            "text": "reply text",
            "comments": [],
            "tasks": []
          }
        ],
        "tasks": [
          {
            "text": "task text",
            "state": "RESOLVED"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

The Target JSON:

- Array(s) with Objects
- each comment or tasks is a "children" (recursive!)

---

```
[
  {
    "text": "comment text",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "reply text",
        "type": "comment"
      },
      {
        "text": "task text",
        "state": "RESOLVED"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

I've started with:

```
  data = data.values.filter((e)=>{
    return e.action === 'COMMENTED';
  }).map((e)=>{
      // hmmm recursion needed, how to solve?
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with:

```
let data = response.data.values
.filter(e => e.action === 'COMMENTED')
.map(function e({comment, commentAnchor}) {

  return {
    commentAnchor,
    text: comment.text,
    children: [...comment.comments.map(function recursion(comment) {

      if (typeof comment === 'undefined') {
        return {};
      }

      let children = [];

      if (comment.comments) {
        children.push(...comment.comments.map(recursion));
      }

      if (comment.tasks) {
        children.push(...comment.tasks);
      }

      let _return = {
        ...comment,
        text: comment.text
      };

      _return.children = children;

      return _return;

    }), ...comment.tasks]
  }
```

});

Answer (score 3):

```
 data = data.values.filter(e => e.action === 'COMMENTED')
    .map(function recursion({comment}){
     return {
      text: comment.text,
      children: [...comment.comments.map(recursion), ...comment.tasks];
     };
    });
```